# How to use Konqueror in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: konqueror

I found Konqueror very good if you want to organize a lot in your own data (copy, move, map, etc.). In Nautilus, you can not show the full directory tree (actually only one, the current one). So you need in Nautilus then two or even more windows, bad to keep track.

My problem:
I completely reorganize my files in a new directory tree according to the 5-folder principle (eg 2.3.1 to 2.3.5), so I have to put old files in order in this new structure. I have to know for a file to be copied, where to put it. In Konqueror I see the directory tree and can make the choice among several candidates.

Who knows a practical solution?

Comment: Please don't include data that can identify you. It is visible to everyone including spammers.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the panels in Konqueror like here:
[image]
And drag files between the panels

[Some help from Konqueror's web site](https://konqueror.org/features/filemanager.php)